# Should we discourage perpetuating trolls by meme-fying them?

Tags: discussion, community

Everybody knows what I'm talking about (if you don't, never mind). It is indisputable that there are memes in this community that positively reinforce trolls in their behaviour by shovelling massive amounts of attention in their direction. [Gilles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/56/gilles) raised my conciousness the other day in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5989182#5989182) in pointing out how counter-productive this is.

But *how* problematic is this? Is it really such a problem? **Should we flag all instances** where somebody uses that meme (in questions, answers, comments and even chat)?

Comment: i hate passive aggressive questions like this... What/who exactly are you talking about? Posting about this without saying what exactly is causing the problem leads to vague and non helpful responses (not saying that any on this page are non helpful)

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: 1) This isn't passive aggressive. 2) I was *asking* if the issue is actually problematic, because I notice this meme gaining popularity in chat every day. 3) I intentionally avoided to mention the specifics in order not to further add fuel to flames. 4) If you state that a vague question must lead to vague answers and in the same sentence say that you do not think this question has generated such answers, you are basically saying this is not a vague question. So, thanks, I guess.

Comment: No i said that I dont necessarily think that the answers here are unhelpful. They are all very vague like your question. And it is passive aggressive because you're talking about a problem (aggressive) but refuse to talk about its source (passive).

Comment: *"Everybody knows what I'm talking about"* -> nope, I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: @Wikis: Sorry, then. See update.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I hesitate to call it "massive amounts of attention". It comes up on occasion, there's a handful of lines in chat responding, and then it gets dropped. Have you noticed the troll seems to respond by posting to comments made about him/her? For example, if the troll is talked about in chat, does a post suddenly appear? *I* have not noticed a pattern like this, but admittedly I'm not monitoring the person in that way. Frankly, our troll seems pretty laissez-faire, posting without rhyme or reason. Yes, feeding the troll probably incites more behaviors.

But his/her behaviors don't really impact me negatively, so for your question "Is it really such a problem?" my answer is No, not for me. I would flag something grossly inappropriate regarding our troll, but the mere fact that "Hey, So-and-so's made another post" isn't going to alarm me or really blip on my radar.

Have the mods been asked how they want us to proceed in the case of a sighting?

Comment: Yes, IIRC the mods (Gilles) explicitly acknowledged that my approach (`edit out Terminators, keep the cannoli`) is the prefered one about a week ago on chat

Comment: Can we edit cannoli into all questions?

Answer (score -3):

The first rule of our troll is: You do not talk about our troll. The second rule of our troll is: *You do not talk about our troll*. Third rule of our troll: someone yells flag, goes to chat, posts meta, the troll is over. Fourth rule: only two trolls to a fight. Fifth rule: one flag at a time, fellas. Sixth rule: no robots, no time-travelling. Seventh rule: trolls **will go on as long as they have to**. And the eighth and final rule: if this is your first sight of our troll, you have to flag.

(In all seriousness, the "troll" we are talking about seems harmless, can be humorous at times, and most importantly: *most of his "queries" are appended onto legitimate quality questions that are welcome in our community.*)